# Explain why the following statement is false

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

Let $f:S^1 \to S^1$ be given by $f(z)=z^2$, where $z=x+iy, x^2+y^2=1$. 
    Then there is a unique lift $\bar f: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ with the properties that 
        (i) $\bar f(1)=0$ and
        (ii) $E \circ \bar f=f$, where $E:\mathbb{R} \to S^1$ is 
    the map $E(t)=e^{2\pi it}=\cos(2\pi t)+i\sin(2\pi t)$.

I thought this statement is true and I have proved it, which is completely worng proof, as I just been told by a professor that is a false statement. Can anyone help me to explain why it is a false statement?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint: if $f$ did factor through $\mathbb{R}$, its induced morphism on the fundamental group of $S^1$ would be trivial.

Comment: I know the fundamental group of $S^1$ is $Z$, which is not trivial. but may I ask what your meant by $f$ factor through $R$?

Comment: If you lifted $f$ to $\overline{f}: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ then the homomorphism $\overline{f}_*$ would be the trivial homomorphism.

Comment: yeah, i know $\pi_1(R)=\{e\}$, so sure the homomorphism $\bar f_* : \pi (S^1) \to \pi (R) $ is trivial. but I still not sure how this relates to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ induces a homomorphism $f_*$ where $f_*(\pi_1(S^1)) \cong 2\mathbb{Z}$.  However, supposing you can lift $f$ to $\overline{f}$ then $\overline{f}_*$ induces a homomorphism into the trivial group $\pi_1(\mathbb{R})$.  Note that $E(t) = e^{2\pi it}$ is a covering map for $S^1$ and induces a homomorphism $E_*:\pi_1(\mathbb{R}) \to \pi_1(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.  Therefore $f_* \neq E_*\circ \overline{f}_*$.

Answer (score 1):

The degree of the map $z \rightarrow z^2$  is 2.But if it factor through $R$ then the map is homotopically trival and so degree is zero which is a contradiction.